# Inconsistency in question and answer display order between network profile and site profile

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, profile-page, network-profile

This is my [network profile's account page](https://stackexchange.com/users/19861698/nai54?tab=accounts):

[image: Picture of accounts page on network profile, which shows the number of questions, then the number of answers]

But this is my [Meta SE profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/879421/nai54?tab=profile):

[image: Picture of Meta SE profile page, which shows the number of answers, then questions]

Notice how on my network one, **the number of questions I have asked come before the number of questions I have *answered*, but on my site one, the number of answers comes first.**

Could this small inconsistency be fixed?

---

My question is not a duplicate of [the proposed duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320459/why-dont-we-give-visual-priority-to-top-answers-over-top-questions-in-the-netwo) at all. My question is why the little bar for each site first lists the number of questions and *then* answers, which is inconsistent with individual site profiles, which lists answers *then* questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't we give visual priority to top answers over top questions in the network profile page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320459/why-dont-we-give-visual-priority-to-top-answers-over-top-questions-in-the-netwo)

Comment: @Ollie No, not at all. I will edit my reasoning into my post.